# Writing to a screen in Shell Script

Tags: shell-script, gnu-screen

I am trying to write the time in a screen in shell script, however, I am extremely inexperienced with the `screen` command. Thus, apologies for my mistakes.
I have a transmitter that operates in a screen created by the shell script I wrote, as follows:

```
screen -S trans -L /dev/ttyACM0
screen -S trans -X stuff 's'$(echo -ne '\015')
sleep 8s
screen -S trans -X quit
```

I am not quite sure what the second line is echoing. Nevertheless, this code produces a `screenlog.0` file at the end of the process, and my goal is to write the time (`$(date)`) at the *end* of this file. Thank you.

Comment: With echo 'stuff' >> File you can add something to the end of a file. Btw this script is rather advanced, did you write it yourself?

Comment: most of it, yes :)

Comment: $(echo -ne '\015') will be a CR / carriage return character, the enter without the newline (that is hex 10) the character with hex code 13 (octal code 15). `-n` is no newline, `-e` to interpret backslash character (\n,\015...). you're sending the command `stuff 's'CR`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds simple enough, let me know if I missed something.

At the end of that script, last line put:

```
date >> screenlog.0
```

entire script:

```
screen -S trans -L /dev/ttyACM0
screen -S trans -X stuff 's'$(echo -ne '\015')
sleep 8s
screen -S trans -X quit
date >> screenlog.0
```

Comment: just `date`, and no `"$(date)"`?

Comment: @Ptheguy Good times! up-vote my answer if you think it helped. :)

Comment: Man, I don't have enough reputations to up vote, sorry

Comment: You can vote anyway, it just won't be displayed in the count